# define the head expressions

Tags: lambda-calculus

List $[E1,E2,...,Ek]$ in lambda expression can write as

$$λc.λn.cE1(cE2(...(cEkn)...))$$

Based on this, how to define `head` and `empty` lambda expressions

So that

$head[M..]$
can be beta reduce to M

and

$empty[]$ can be beta-reduce to True

$empty[N..]$ can be beta-reduce to False

So far I only figured out the True and False in lambda expression are

$$T=(λx.λy.x)$$
$$F=(λx.λy.y)$$

Any tips or hints would be very appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your definition of a list, we can define emptyList as $λcn.n$ (same as your above $F$). Then we can simply define your head and empty test functions as $head:=λl.l(λab.a)M, empty:=λl.l(λab.False)True$, where $M$ is an arbitrary expression.
​​

Now you'll have below as expected (here I use a list containing only $h$ as an example of nonempty list):$$head(λcn.chn) \to_\beta (λcn.chn)(λab.a)M \to_\beta (λab.a)hM \to_\beta h \\
empty(emptyList) \to_\beta empty(λcn.n) \to_\beta (λcn.n)(λab.False)True \to_\beta True \\
empty(λcn.chn) \to_\beta (λcn.chn)(λab.False)True \to_\beta (λab.False)hTrue \to_\beta False$$

Comment: @ssa They're syntactically same notation for abstraction with multiple variables, for example see ref [here](https://personal.utdallas.edu/~gupta/courses/apl/lambda.pdf). Of course, you can use your own usual notation as well...

Comment: I still feel it is hard to understand to define the none empty list to $\lambda cn. chn$ . Here `h` is the First elements `E1` but why the rest is represent as `n`

Comment: See my above note (here I use a list containing *only* h as an example of nonempty list), so I'm only use this as an example of a non-empty list with a single element. Of course you can use $λc.λn.cE1R$ as your generic list starting with $E1$, and it's a good exercise for you to verify the results are same for above head/empty functions...